# Add DataColumns by looping through DataGridViewCheckBoxColumn

Tags: vb.net, loops, datagridview, checkbox, datagridviewcolumn

I have two forms in my project. They are named "Criteria" and "Screen".  The Criteria form contains `DataGridViewCriteria`. The Screen form contains `DataGridViewScreen`.

`DataGridViewCriteria`'s first column is a `CheckBoxColumn`.  DataGridViewCriteria's second column contains a description specific to each row.  I need to loop through the CheckBoxColumn and for each `CheckBox` that is checked I need to add a `DataColumn` to DataGridViewScreen. I need the title of each `DataColumn` added to DataGridViewScreen to equal the description that is adjacent its respective `CheckBox` on DataGridViewCriteria.

My code so far is:

```
For Each row As DataGridViewRow In Criteria.DataGridViewCriteria.Rows
        If row.Cells(0).Value = True Then
            Dim col As New DataColumn(row.Cells(1).Value, Type.GetType("System.String"))
            dt.Columns.Add(row.Cells(1).Value)
        End If
    Next
```

Any suggestions? Thank you very much!

Comment: If the CheckBoxColumn is the first column, shouldn't that be "If row.Cells(0).Value = True Then"

Comment: I fixed that in my program but no luck.  Same result.  Later in my project when I try to call on one of the columns it says that the "column does not belong to the table".  Thanks!

Comment: Is the DataGridViewScreen a DataGridView or a DataTable?

Comment: The DataGridViewScreen is a DataGridView that has a DataTable bound to it.